# Subtract current track time from total track time

Tags: vb.net, math, datetime

Hey all i have a song playing that displays the time like so:

0:00 / 4:47

The first time is the tracks current time.
The second is the total track time of that song playing.

I split it like so:

```
Dim tmpTimes As Array = lblSongTime.Text.Split("/")
```

So **tmpTimes(0)** gives me 0:00 and **tmpTimes(1)** gives me 4:47.

Now i tried to subtract the **tmpTimes(1)** from **tmpTimes(0)**

```
Debug.Print(CDbl(tmpTimes(1).replace(":", "") - tmpTimes(0).replace(":", "")))
```

and i get: **447.. 446... 445... etc**

What kind of calulation do i need in order to return a decending count?

Example: **4:47...4:46.....4:45...etc** using the current time **tmpTimes(0)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
Dim times As String() = lblSongTime.Text.Split("/"c)
Dim elapsedTime As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact(times(0).Trim(), "m\:ss", Nothing)
Dim totalTime As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact(times(1).Trim(), "m\:ss", Nothing)
Dim remainingTime As TimeSpan = totalTime - elapsedTime

Debug.WriteLine(remainingTime.ToString("m\:ss"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to split the text MM:SS into Minutes and Seconds, then convert that to total seconds (m * 60 + s).  Then you can do the math on seconds.  Then you will need to convert it back into Minutes and Seconds for display.

You may also be able to use the [Timespan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) class to do this.

Comment: Tried doing this: 

Dim tmpTimes As Array = lblSongTime.Text.Split("/")
Dim timeCurrent As String = tmpTimes(0)
Dim timeCurrentArray As Array = timeCurrent.Split(":")
Debug.Print(timeCurrentArray(0) * 60 + timeCurrentArray(1))
But it does not count down...

Comment: "does not count down" - do you have a timer or event firing as the song plays?  It's not clear if you're having trouble doing the math on the string values, or are having trouble with synchronously updating the count as the song plays.  What are you using to actually play the track?

Comment: It internet radio. I am just grabbing the text on the page as the time left.